# Using Twython to get user ID's from a list of screen names (Twitter API)

Tags: python, api, twitter, twython

I have the code below, which works for querying the Twitter API for screen names, based on a list of known ID's. I want to go the other way around: knowing the screen names, and getting the ID's.

```
from twython import Twython

# Paste your codes here
app_key = '...'
app_secret ='...'
oauth_token = '...-...'
oauth_token_secret= '...'

# Create twitter thing to query
twitter = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)

# What to look up (Twitter id:s)
ids = ["259784090","136953436","1219150098"]

# Create a comma separated string from the previous list
comma_separated_string = ",".join(ids)

# Query twitter with the comma separated list
output = twitter.lookup_user(user_id=comma_separated_string)
username_list=[]

# Loop through the results (Twitter screen names)
for user in output:
    print user['screen_name']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same API call, but with different parameters.

[The documentation for GET users/lookup says](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup)

> Returns fully-hydrated user objects for up to 100 users per request, as specified by comma-separated values passed to the user_id and/or screen_name parameters

Assuming your above use of Twython is correct (I don't use it myself) you should be able to call...

```
# What to look up (Twitter screen_name:s)
ids = ["john","paul","george","ringo"]

# Create a comma separated string from the previous list
comma_separated_string = ",".join(ids)

# Query twitter with the comma separated list
output = twitter.lookup_user(screen_name=comma_separated_string)

username_list=[]

# Loop through the results (Twitter screen names)
for user in output:
    print user["id_str"]
```